# which view is getting loaded in TabControl

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I have 4 tabs, in my application which is been developed in android.
I wanted to know which event is fired when i navigate from one tab to another.

Where should i use this event in my code?

```
public class Test extends TabActivity
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                TabHost host = getTabHost();        
                host.addTab(host.newTabSpec("Test1").setIndicator(new MyView(this, 
                R.drawable.icon, "Test1")).setContent(new Intent(this, Test1.class)));  
                host.addTab(host.newTabSpec("Test2").setIndicator(new MyView(this,  
                R.drawable.compass, "Test2")).setContent(new Intent(this, Test2.class)));
                host.addTab(host.newTabSpec("Test3").setIndicator(new MyView(this,  
                R.drawable.mosquebg, "Test3")).setContent(new Intent(this, 
                Test3.class)));

                host.addTab(host.newTabSpec("Settings").setIndicator(new MyView(this,  
                R.drawable.icon, "Settings")).setContent(new Intent(this, Settings.class)));

                host.getTabWidget().setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background);


                host.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).getLayoutParams().height=35;
                host.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).getLayoutParams().height=35;
                host.getTabWidget().getChildAt(2).getLayoutParams().height=35;
                host.getTabWidget().getChildAt(3).getLayoutParams().height=35;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[setOnTabChangedListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.html#setOnTabChangedListener%28android.widget.TabHost.OnTabChangeListener%29) is the listener you would set up for the [OnTabChanged](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.OnTabChangeListener.html#onTabChanged%28java.lang.String%29) event.